# Detect change of text in a UI Text field when the values are changed from the controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I'm working on an iOS assignment submission and I'm required to change the value of one text field and this change should reflect on 4 other text fields. On a normal scenario "editingChanged" action would suffice, but I'm using my own custom keyboard (Just buttons on the same view) therefore this action does not get called. What would be the most efficient way to detect a change in text when the change is done by the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a variable where you store the value in the ViewController and then in the didSet of that value do the necessary changes:

```
var value: String {
    didSet {
        // do the changes of the others UITextfields here.
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this `var n: String = content {
            didSet {
                txtGrams.text = txtGrams.text! + content } }` it did not work. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the delegate of the `UITextField`, and then implement `func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool`.

Within the body of this function you can change the value of the other text fields